# Telescope of CW-complexes

Tags: algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

Let $X_n$ the n-th term of an ascending sequence of pointed CW-complexes in their homotopy category. Let $X’= \bigcup_{n\geq 1} [n-1, n]^{+} \wedge X_n$ and let $A_1 = \bigcup_{k\geq 1, k odd} [k-1, k]^{+} \wedge X_k$ and $A_2 = \bigcup_{k\geq 0, k even} [k-1, k]^{+} \wedge X_k$.

Why is it true that $A_1 \cap A_2 = \bigvee_k X_k$ and $A_1$ is homotopically equivalent to $\bigvee_{k,odd} X_k$?

This is my very first approach to smash products and wedge sums, so I might be failing to understand some fundamental aspects of their definition. Any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have an ascending sequence of pointed CW-complexes $X _1\subset X_2 \subset X_3 \subset \ldots$ with a common basepoint $* \in X_1$. Noting that $X'_n = [n-1,n]^+ \wedge X_n = ([n-1,n] \times X_n) / ([n-1,n] \times *)$, we see that $X'_n$ deformation retracts to the subspace $\bar X_n = \{n\} \times X_n' \subset X'$ which is a homeomorphic copy of $X_n$.

1. The subspace $\bigcup_n \bar X_n \subset X'$ is nothing else than the disjoint sum of the $X_n$ with all basepoints $* \in X_n$ identified to a single point, i.e. $\bigcup_n \bar X_n \approx \bigvee_n X_n$.
2. Similarly the subspace $A_ 1 = \bigcup_{n \text{ odd}} X'_n \subset X'$ is nothing else than the disjoint sum of the $X'_n$, $n$ odd,  with all basepoints $* \in X'_n$ identified to a single point, i.e. $\bigcup_{n \text{ odd}} X'_n \approx \bigvee_{n \text{ odd}} X'_n$.
3. By construction $A_1 \cap A_2 = \bigcup_n \bar X_n$, i.e. $A_1 \cap A_2 \approx \bigvee_n X_n$.
4. Since each $X'_n$ deformation retracts to $\bar X_n$, we see that $A_1$ deformation retracts to $\bigcup_{n \text{ odd}} \bar X_n \approx \bigvee_{n \text{ odd}} X_n$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have a couple of (maybe trivial) questions though: why does $X’_{n}$ deformation retracts to $\bar{X_n}$? And why is this last one an homeomorphic copy of $X_n$?

Comment: $\bar X_n$ is the image of the embedding $X_n \to X', x \mapsto [n,x]$, hence it is a homeomorphic copy of $X_n$. And the "projection" $p_n : [n-1,n] \times X_n \to \{n\} \times X_n, p_n(t,x) = (n,x)$, is a strong deformation retraction via $R_n : [n-1,n] \times X_n \times I \to   [n-1,n] \times X_n, R_n(t,x,s) = (s(n-t) + t ,x)$. It maps $ [n-1,n] \times * \times I$ to $(n,*)$ and thus induces a pointed strong deformation retraction $X'_n \to \bar X_n$.